# iOS - Amazon Cognito + Kinesis Video as a guest user

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-kinesis

**TLDR:** How to use Amazon services with a guest/unauthenticated user ?

I have been trying to implement Amazon Kinesis video stream with a guest user to no avail. Here is what I have done or got so far.

1. Followed this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-ios.html) and have a project ready to use with both user pool and identity pool setup.
2. Have enabled unauthenticated access in my identity pool as stated in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html).
3. I have gone over [Getting Credentials doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html) but I don't think I fully understood what I needed to do. I have tried it as I understood it but did not succeed (Posting the code below).
4. Have verified using the policy simulator that the roles (both Auth And UnAuth) created & associated with the identity pool have the permissions for the job (Both roles have same permissions).

Now, the thing is that it works perfectly with an amazon cognito authenticated user, but not for a guest user. The code base I have is of the sample project provided by Amazon in the first link above. To try the guest user, I just skip the login page and land directly on the channels page in the [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-ios.git). There I just invoke `createSignalingChannel` or `describeSignalingChannel` on `AWSKinesisVideo` and get the following error in XCode:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSKinesisVideoErrorDomain Code=1 "null" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=null, NSLocalizedFailureReason=AccessDeniedException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/}
```

I have been looking for a way to do this for a couple of days now and the only information I have found in the documentations etc is that it is possible but have not how to do it. I think the only step that is missing is connecting the app or accessing the services as a guest user or . Console etc configuration are all set.

Code for creating channel for Kinesis video Stream sharing:

```
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: .USEast2, identityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .USEast2, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWith(block: { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        if (task.error != nil) {
            print("Error: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            // the task result will contain the identity id
            // let cognitoId = task.result!
            // I don't know what to do here or what to do with this Id, this code block is here
            // because it was part of getting credentials link. I have tried without it as well
        }

        return task;

    })

    //        let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: self.awsRegionType, credentialsProvider: AWSMobileClient.default())
    AWSKinesisVideo.register(with: configuration!, forKey: awsKinesisVideoKey) // "kinesisvideo" 

    self.retrieveChannelARN(channelName: channelNameValue)
    if self.channelARN == nil {
        self.createChannel(channelName: channelNameValue)
    }
```

`retrieveChannelARN` and `createChannel` methods are unchanged, they are part of the [sample code](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-ios/blob/master/Swift/KVSiOSApp/ChannelConfigurationViewController.swift), as follows:

```
func createChannel(channelName: String) {
    let kvsClient = AWSKinesisVideo(forKey: awsKinesisVideoKey)
    let createSigalingChannelInput = AWSKinesisVideoCreateSignalingChannelInput.init()
    createSigalingChannelInput?.channelName = channelName
    kvsClient.createSignalingChannel(createSigalingChannelInput!).continueWith(block: { (task) -> Void in
        if let error = task.error {
            print("Error creating channel \(error)")
            return
        } else {
            self.channelARN = task.result?.channelARN
            print("Channel ARN : ", task.result?.channelARN)
        }
    }).waitUntilFinished()
    if (self.channelARN == nil) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Unable to create channel",
                                                message: "Please validate all the input fields",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
}

func retrieveChannelARN(channelName: String) {
    if !channelName.isEmpty {
        let describeInput = AWSKinesisVideoDescribeSignalingChannelInput()
        describeInput?.channelName = channelName
        let kvsClient = AWSKinesisVideo(forKey: awsKinesisVideoKey)
        kvsClient.describeSignalingChannel(describeInput!).continueWith(block: { (task) -> Void in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Error describing channel: \(error)")
            } else {
                self.channelARN = task.result?.channelInfo?.channelARN
                print("Channel ARN : ", task.result!.channelInfo!.channelARN ?? "Channel ARN empty.")
            }
        }).waitUntilFinished()
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Channel Name is Empty",
                                                message: "Valid Channel Name is required.",
                                                preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
}
```

Also I have noticed that `internalCredentials` property of `credentialsProvider` are present in authenticated user but not for the guest user, I just don't know how to remedy that. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you!

[Identity Pool Settings](https://ibb.co/zrJ081p)

[UnAuthRole](https://ibb.co/TTR8M6M)

[AuthRole](https://ibb.co/qsWRtbp)

Comment: You are getting AccessDeniedException which means your role doesn't have permission for the operation/

Comment: I wish mate, but like I mentioned, I have verified that the roles attached with the identity pool, have the permissions needed for the Kinesis video stream. Permissions I gave to those roles are the ones given by Amazon in the documentation (1st link in my post in Point1). I have also verified via policy simulator that the methods being called, createChannel and retrieveChannelARN can be performed on both Auth and UnAuth roles attached with the identity pool.

Comment: @usman, I have added images for identity pool settings and UnAuthRole so you can verify that those things are in order.

Comment: @Abdul91 can you please attached the AuthRole too?

Comment: I have added the image for AuthRole mate